# fullpage.js menu from fixed bottom to fixed top

Tags: jquery, css, fullpage.js

i am using fullPage.js for my website,

Is there any way to make the menu sticky.

In first section menu is fixed bottom and in second section menu is fixed top.

Am trying to achieve this menu effect http://www.dadaabstories.org/

Thank you all for your awesome support.

cheers
berney

Answer (score 0):

Here you have [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/2RPu6/).

It did it quite fast but maybe there's a more simple way to do it.
Basically it's about playing with the callbacks and the CSS styles.

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    slidesColor: ['yellow', 'orange', '#C0C0C0', '#ADD8E6'],
    onLeave: function (index, direction) {
        if (index == 1 && direction == "down") {
            var menuTop = $(window).height() - $('#myMenu').height();


            $('#myMenu').css('top', '').css('bottom', menuTop + 'px');
        }
        if (index == 2 && direction == "up") {
            var menuTop = $(window).height() - $('#myMenu').height();

            $('#myMenu').animate({
                top: menuTop + 'px',
            }, 300);

            $('#myMenu').css('bottom', '');
        }

    }
});
```